# JavaFx: Get the clicked button value

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How does the following code get the value of a button?

```
String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
```

Comment: I presume this code is from within an event handler?

Comment: `event.getSource()` returns the `Node` that triggers the event. In this case, it's a `Button`. `Button` has a `getText()` method. Go check out the Java docs.

Comment: what happened when you tried it .. ;)

Comment: @Sedrick `event.getSource()` returns `Object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet that may make it clearer :

```
    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        Object node = event.getSource(); //returns the object that generated the event
        System.out.println(node instanceof Button); //prints true. demonstrates the source is a Button
        //since the returned object is a Button you can cast it to one
        Button b = (Button)node;
        System.out.println(b.getText());//prints out Click Me
    });
```

The practical short form of the above verbose handler could be :

```
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println(((Button)event.getSource()).getText());//prints out Click Me
    });
```

In case the handler is used for a specific button as is this snippet it could be:

```
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println(button.getText());//prints out Click Me
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and this helped.

```
private void loadWhenClicked(ActionEvent event){
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    System.out.println(button.getText()); // prints out button's text
}
```

As @Sedrick has mentioned, event.getSource returns an object. And since you know that the object is a Button object, you cast it into one.
(I apologize if I didn't answer according to any rule since this is my first answer :D)

Comment: weeeeell ... you shouldn't copy other answers - there's nothing new in here compared to the accepted answer, is there ;)